# Forcing $M[G] \models CH$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I have seen the proof of transitioning from a model in which **CH** holds to a model in which **CH** fails. However, how do we force the other direction? More explicitly, suppose that $M$ is a countable, transative model of **ZFC** and $M \models \neg$ **CH**. What poset $\mathbb{P} \in M$ do we use to find a generic filter $G$ over $\mathbb{P}$ such that $M[G] \models$ **CH**?

Thanks.

Comment: The title and the body ask different things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Just noticed. Changed. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can always collapse the continuum to be $\aleph_1$. Namely, $\Bbb P$ is the partial order whose conditions are countable partial functions from $\omega_1$ to $\Bbb R$, ordered by reverse inclusion (or inclusion, if you work by the Jerusalem convention).

Genericity arguments show that the generic defines a surjection from $\omega_1$ onto the real numbers, but this forcing is also countably closed so it adds no new real numbers. Therefore $\sf CH$ holds in the extension.

Comment: So it is essentially identical to the forcing in the other direction?

Comment: What do you mean essentially identical?

Comment: Oh nevermind! I see where I messed up.